# Chat server with user engagement in node.js

Tags: node.js, chat

I would like to build a chat server in node.js ; i need to handle user engagement such as Fastpath plugin in Openfire so that when a request arrives it is sent to a certain operator [the first free, for example ]... is there a similar module/library for node.js? I would like to use node instead of openfire.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/). There are plenty of examples of chat servers written in it.